# Does calling a thread's method from another thread pause that's thread execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Say I call a thread's method from inside another thread as such

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //do something
    TestThread thread = new TestThread();
    thread.start();
    thread.doSomething();
    //Part A
}

class TestThread extends Thread
{
   public void run()
   {
       //do something
   }

    public void doSomething()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Will the program do everything in the `doSomething()` method before moving onto partA or will it start running the `doSomething()` method then move straight onto part A?
I'm making an application with a server serving multiple clients and want the server to be able to quickly move through the requests, so it should be once it is sent it moves on rather than waiting for the client to process the instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The main thread will run `doSomething()` while the `thread`-thread will be running `run()` as usual.

Just because `doSomething()` is in a class that extends `Thread` doesn't mean that there's anything special about it as a method.

Comment: Thank  you, thought that might have been the case